# Clear and populate multiple sheets with data in a single request

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I need to periodically clear the data in multiple sheets and re-populate them with data (via the Google Sheets API v4). To do this, I'm executing 2 separate requests for each sheet (1 clear & 1 update). This is kind of a slow process when the user is sitting there waiting for it. It seems to me that each new request significantly adds to the completion time. If I could wrap all these into a single batch-command request, it might help a lot.

I'm currently doing this for each sheet...

```
service.spreadsheets()
  .values()
  .clear(idSpreadsheet, sheetTitle + "!$A$1:$Y", new ClearValuesRequest())
  .execute();

service.spreadsheets()
  .values()
  .update(idSpreadsheet, range, new ValueRange().setValues(values))
  .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
  .execute();
```

I don't see a way to just wrap a bunch of generic commands into a single batch request. I see that `DeleteDimensionRequest` and `AppendCellsRequest` can be wrapped into a batch, but I can't really find a good `AppendCellsRequest` example (and it seems that people recommend my current `values().update()` method anyway).

Can anyone recommend a good way to streamline this? Or am I already doing it the best way?

Comment: Use the Google APIs Explorer to determine the needed combination of requests for a single `batchUpdate` call to do what you want, then reproduce the required arguments using the Java client library methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know if I'm doing it the BEST way, but I was able to accomplish my goal of clearing and populating multiple sheets with data in a single batch request. The trick was to not use the `clear()` method but instead, overwrite the the sheet with blank data using `RepeatCellRequest`. Also, now using `AppendCellsRequest` instead of `update()`. These two requests can be wrapped in a batch request.
My early tests with 3 sheets, shows about a 25% performance improvement. Not spectacular, but it helps.

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
for (SheetData mySheet : sheetDatas)
{
    List<List<Object>> values = mySheet.getValues();
    Request clearSheetRequest = new Request()
          .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
            .setRange(new GridRange()
              .setSheetId(mySheet.getSheetId())
            )
            .setFields("*")
            .setCell(new CellData())
          );

    List<RowData> preppedRows = new ArrayList<RowData>();
    for (List<Object> row : values)
    {
    RowData preppedRow = new RowData();
    List<CellData> cells = new ArrayList<CellData>();
    for (Object value : row)
    {
        CellData cell = new CellData();
        ExtendedValue userEnteredValue = new ExtendedValue();
        if (value instanceof String)
        {
            userEnteredValue.setStringValue((String) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Double)
        {
            userEnteredValue.setNumberValue((Double) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Integer)
        {
            userEnteredValue.setNumberValue(Double.valueOf((Integer) value).doubleValue());
        }
        else if (value instanceof Boolean)
        {
            userEnteredValue.setBoolValue((Boolean) value);
        }
        cell.setUserEnteredValue(userEnteredValue);
        cells.add(cell);
    }
    preppedRow.setValues(cells);
    preppedRows.add(preppedRow);
    }

    Request appendCellsRequest = new Request().setAppendCells(
    new AppendCellsRequest()
        .setSheetId(mySheet.getSheetId())
        .setRows(preppedRows)
        .setFields("*")
        );

    requests.add(clearSheetRequest);
    requests.add(appendCellsRequest);
}

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batch = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse batchResponse = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(idSpreadsheet, batch).execute();
```

Comment: If you only want to clear values (based on your question code), you can use [`values().batchClear`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/BatchClearValuesRequest.html) to clear all the needed sheets' ranges of values in 1 request. Alternately, specify the appropriate field (i.e. `fields: "userEnteredValue"`) in your above `clearSheetRequest` to limit its scope - this may improve performance. You may also be able to use `BatchUpdateValuesRequest` given that you know the size of `values`